# Prove that a surjective map $f:R\to R'$ such that $f(r_1r_2)=f(r_1)f(r_2)$ satisfies f(1)=1

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $R,R'$ be rings. Prove that a surjective map $f:R\to R'$ such that $f(r_1r_2)=f(r_1)f(r_2)$ for all $r_1,r_2\in R$ satisfies $f(1)=1$.

Is it enough to show that
\begin{align*}
y&=f(x)=f(1\cdot x)=f(1)f(x)=f(1)y,\\
y&=f(x)=f(x\cdot 1)=f(x)f(1)=yf(1).\\
\end{align*}
and that this shows that $f(1\cdot x)=f(x\cdot 1)=y$ and therefore $f(1)$ is the identity such that $f(1)=1$? Of course there's more wording to my proof and supposing of stuff, but this is the idea. Is this correct or is there more to it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The easiest way is probably this: surjectivity provides the existence of $x\in R$ with $f(x)=1$. Then $f(1)=f(1)f(x)=f(1\cdot x)=f(x)=1$.